# Конвертация из doc в docx python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

Я хочу конвертировать файлы .doc для работы python-docx. Подскажите как это сделать, не используя win32com.client, чтобы это работало и на mac os и на linux.

Comment: изучи сначала структуру файлов doc и docx. Найди в них разницу. Если эту разницу можно решить просто заменой текста - то по сути подойдет метод replace. Если там большая разница - то надо считать всё из файла doc, проанализировать. И сгенерировать docx

Comment: doc и docx абсолютно разные форматы. И если docx это упрощённо XML с примочками, то doc невероятно сложен. Вы не можете преобразовать из одного формата в другой чистым питоном, нужен код из самого MS Office.

Comment: @viilpe открою секрет. Конвертировать можно даже из .exe windows в linux программу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472691/5741205